# Weird Hibernate Error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, exception

I'm working on a Java project and I'm confused as to what's happening with a situation I've stumbled upon.

I'm developing on a mac with mac osx mountain lion. I'm using eclipse and have everything configured correctly, and have been developing this way for a long time without issues.

I'm using MySQL and Hibernate with HBM mapping files, I'm using Spring to tie it all together by indicating what mapping files should be used. Recently I attempted to add a new column to a table, updated the domain objects, and updated the hbm mapping files.

Now, I started to get an error:

Unknown column 'dateSent' in 'field list'

even though the column was in my mapping file and the column was in the database and also in my domain object.

I then removed it and rebuilt everything with Maven, now I'm getting an even weirder issue where my code has all references to the column removed, the column is removed from the database, and the column is removed from the hbm mapping file. However, I'm still seeing Hibernate throwing an error about the column as if it still exists somewhere in my code but it doesn't. Even weirder, the Hibernate output doesn't show improper use of attempting to insert a record with the column in question...  see below in error: "Hibernate: insert into messages (userid, content, location) values (?, ?, ?)"...

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
        Hibernate: insert into messages (userid, content, location) values (?, ?, ?)
        18:08:19,154  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:77 - SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
        18:08:19,155 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - Unknown column 'dateSent' in 'field list'
        18:08:19,175 ERROR MessageProcessorImpl:724 - org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not insert: [com.app.domain.Message]; SQL [insert into messages (userid, content, location) values (?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.app.domain.Message]
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:629)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'dateSent' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2643)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2362)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2280)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2265)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:33)
    ... 66 more
```

Is there anything like cache between the mysql database or java applications using Hibernate that could cause this?

I've restarted my computer, performed a Maven clean / Maven install to refresh everything. Searched my code for the string dateSent and didn't find reference to the word in my code and it's still complaining.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the HBM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.app.domain">
    <class name="Message" table="messages" >
        <id name="messageId" column="messageId">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="userId" column="userId"/>
        <property name="content" column="content"/>
        <property name="location" column="location"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here's my domain object:

```
package com.app.domain;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Message {
    private long messageId;
    private long userId;
    private String content;
    private String location;

    public long getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }
    public void setMessageId(long messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }
    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you, or did you, have any mapping for a column with the name `preSurgicalReminderSent`?

Comment: Sorry, that was in error in my example, I changed the name of the column in my example and missed that in the code sample.

Comment: The example now has the correct edited output above.

Comment: Try deleting your local Maven repository, then rebuilding.

Comment: Great idea, trying that now!

Answer (score 0):

I went as far as reverting my codebase to the last stable revision and I was still having the issue. The problem ended up being due to a history trigger on the table referencing the field I removed.

The exception message seems to have been inaccurately indicating the problem was with my mapping.